# Dropdown option changes based on max number and other dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, dropdownbox

I have a page with 2 dropdown boxes. One is used for picking a number of adults, the other is for the number of children.

The total combined max of the selection can not be higher than 10. So if for example pick 4 in adults the number of options in the children dropdown will be 0 to 6. If I pick 9 in adults the options in the children dropdown will only be 0 and 1. THe total combined selection can never get above 10.

I am fairly new to JS/jQuery. Can anyone give me tips or point me in the right direction?

/Michael

Comment: What you can do is, you can have change event of 1st dropDown, and on that just verify its value, and subtract it from 10 and then add that number options into children dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#ddlAdult").change(function(){
              console.log("In");
              var value = parseInt($(this).val());
              var optionsToBeCreated = 10 - value;
              var count =0;
              $("#ddlChildren").empty(); 
              console.log(optionsToBeCreated);
              while(count <= optionsToBeCreated)
              {
                  console.log("In");
                  $("#ddlChildren").append("<option value="+count+">"+count+"</option");
                  count = count + 1;
              }
          });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlAdult">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <select id="ddlChildren">
    </select>
```

Comment: Very close to what I am looking for. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

Save the code below in HTML and run in browser. This will work as you expected.

```html
 


    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
    var adultValue=0;
    var childValue=0;
    var valueChk=0;
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
            $(".adult").append('<option value='+i+'>'+i+'</option>');
            $( ".adult" ).change(function() {
              adultValue=$( ".adult" ).val();
             // alert(adultValue);
              valueChk=10-adultValue;
              $('.child')
                                                .find('option')
                                                .remove()
                                                .end();
               for(j=0;j<=valueChk;j++)
               {
                        $(".child").append('<option value='+j+'>'+j+'</option>');
               }        
              
            });        
            
            $( ".child" ).change(function() {
             
              valueChk=parseInt($( ".adult" ).val())+parseInt($( ".child" ).val());
              alert(valueChk);
            });        
            
    });


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select class="adult">

    </select>
    <select class="child">
    </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Also very close to what am looking for. Thank you very much :)